# jedis sort by map(download,browse,upload)

Tags: java, redis

ex:

```
datatype:resource{(download,1),(browse,2)}
```

how to sort by capacity of download or capacity of browse in java?

```
jedis.sort(key,sortingParameters);
```

Is that ok?

Comment: sorted map sounds like Treemap. it will sort automatically by key 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_treemap_class.htm

Comment: in another word，I need sort the map of field in redis,but jedis don't support this method,so...